# Detect source of watcher change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way, to detect to source of a change to a watched property in AngularJS?

For example (very rudimentary), I have the global value:

```
let watchMe = 0;
```

and I watch it in a component like:

```
$scope.$watch(() => {
  return watchMe;
}, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  if(newValue !== oldValue) {
    console.log(`watchMe changed to ${newValue}, but who changed it??`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no possible.

A way to detect it would be to use functions which set the value. And because you should know where this specific function was used you can determine which part of your code called the function.

Comment: That's kinda unsatisfying. I hoped for some sort of stacktrace to the watched value.

Comment: That would be functionality which have to be provided by the js engine. But the js engines doesn't support it. A dirty hack would be to create an error and parse the stacktrace. But this might not work.

Comment: Of course the JS engine does provide a stacktrace. Just log something with console.error() and you will receive a stracktrace.

Comment: Yes, like I wrote. It would be dirty hack. Because you always have to create an error: `const err = new Error(); console.log(err.stack);`

Comment: I just discovered console.trace() :) that does not solve the problem totally, but maybe its a try.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it might not work. The most stable and maintainable way would be to use functions which change the variable and in which you can handle the logic you want to handle.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for Angular's `$watch` callback is `function(newVal, oldVal, scope)`. Since that's the only information you have available to work with, you can't determine what changed the value within a `$watch` callback.

However, if the `watchMe` value is only changed in a reasonable number of locations, you can forego the `$watch` and instead use `$broadcast` and `$on` to manage changes to your values.

The advantage of `$broadcast` is that it allows you to pass arbitrary data along with the event. You can use the event along with your passed data to determine what caused the change.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('BugController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$interval', BugController]);

function BugController($scope, $rootScope, $interval) {
  $scope.bugCount = 5;
  $scope.message = "Let's fix those bugs!";

  $scope.changeBug = function(change, person) {
    var oldValue = $scope.bugCount;
    var newValue = $scope.bugCount = Math.max(0, $scope.bugCount + change);

    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
      //$broadcast an event.
      //parameters indicate the change in value and who changed it.
      $rootScope.$broadcast('bugs-changed', newValue, oldValue, person);
    }

  };

  //Listen for bugs-changed events
  //Use the included parameters to identify who caused the value to change.
  $scope.$on('bugs-changed', function(event, newValue, oldValue, person) {
    $scope.message = person +
      ' changed bugCount from ' +
      oldValue + ' to ' + newValue + '.';
      
    if (newValue > oldValue) {
      $scope.message += ' Dang it, ' + person + '!';
    }
    else {
      $scope.message += ' Good job, ' + person + '!';
    }
  });
  
  //And random bugs pop up over time
  $interval(function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('bugs-changed', $scope.bugCount + 1, $scope.bugCount++, 'Time')
  }, 5000);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="BugController">
    <div>Bugs: {{bugCount}}</div>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <p>
      Alex
      <button ng-click="changeBug(1, 'Alex')">Add bug</button>
      <button ng-click="changeBug(-1, 'Alex')">Fix bug</button>
    </p>

    <p>
      David
      <button ng-click="changeBug(1, 'David')">Add bug</button>
      <button ng-click="changeBug(2, 'David')">Fix bug</button>
    </p>

  </div>

</div>
```